# Failed building wheel for pyCGNS

Tags: python, cgns

I've exported a .CGNS file from paraview and trying to import in the Python to extract some of the data, but while I tried to install the pyCGNS, it shows an error.

I tried to use pip install pyCGNS, but showing following error.

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
 python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
 exit code: 1
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyCGNS
 ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyCGNS, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: This might be due to missing dependencies or a configuration problem. Try installing the required dependencies mentioned in the pyCGNS documentation or check if you have the necessary build tools installed on your system.